# how to upload files via nodejs API - Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to Vuejs and working on a project that requires to upload files. I am using this vue component https://github.com/TerryZ/v-uploader. The problem is that i am not able to get the file object to pass through my custom API and also the documentation is not done properly.
Any help will be appreciated
Below is my code

```
<template>
  <!-- v-bind 'setting' data to config file uploader -->
  <!-- bind event 'done' to receive file uploaded info -->
  <v-uploader :setting="uploadConfig" @done="uploadDone" ></v-uploader>
</template>

<style lang="css">
.info-show{
    margin-top:10px;
}
</style>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {                
            uploadConfig: {
                multiple: true,
                language: 'en', //default: 'cn'
                itemLimit: 5,
                fileSizeLimit:'3MB',
                fileTypeExts: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png']
            }
        }
    },
    methods:{
        //receive file uploaded info
        //@type Array
        uploadDone(files){
            if(files && Array.isArray(files) && files.length){
                // do something...
            }
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: is it imported properly into your main.js file? are you seeing any errors?

Comment: @DanOswalt yes i have imported in main.js file and the component is working in the sense that i am able to select files and set different parameters. Only i am not able to get the fileObject from the component and that is crucial

Comment: You tagged your question with `node.js` but provide no node.js code. Please include any relevant code; it will help us understand and re-produce your problem. We also do not know exactly what your problem is. Are you getting any errors? What is the file object? Please read through this help article and update your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.